# Excel array formula - managing data in table with dynamic height

Tags: arrays, excel, dynamic, height

I have a working array formula, which creates a list of values in column A. The length of the list depends on the input values of the formula and will vary over time. Values could be removed and added anywhere in the list, not necessarily at the end. Now in column B I want to manually add comments on the values in column A. When the length of the list changes, the values in column B don't move along with the values in column A, so they are not longer on the correct line. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the OFFSET function for the dynamic variable.